# How to show different metadata based on current user in OData Web API?

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am using ASP.NET Web API 2.2 OData v5.4.0. I'm trying to implement authentication for OData and faced the following issue: different users can have different access rights on entities. Is it possible to show different service descriptions and $metadata documents based on current user identity?

MapODataServiceRoute() method accepts the entire EDM model, so it can't be changed after route is mapped.